# How to hide the text when wrapping?

Tags: android, textview

```
<TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvVExample"
        android:textColor="#496933"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

For example, the text is:

```
Having desirable or positive qualities especially those suitable for a thing specified
```

And it shows me:

```
Having desirable or positive qualities especially those suita
specified
```

It can wrap. And It shows two lines but some words is hidden

What I expected is:

```
Having desirable or positive qualities especially those 
suitable for a thing specified
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this issue in XML Editor or the App it self. Usually it is noticed that the XML Rendering isn't proper. But when it runs on the device its correct

Comment: This TextView is in a Linear or Relative layout?

Comment: It is the issue in the App and the parent is GridLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I find the solution, if the TextView which is the child of GridLayout. I can't set the width to WRAP_CONTECT becacuse it will use the whole row as the width but not the width of the cell. The solution is that set the width to 0dp and set the layout_gravity to fill_horizontal. Also, the width of the gridlayout must be MATCH_PARENT.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
.
.
.

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvVExample"
    android:textColor="#496933"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
.
.
.
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems in many cases the trick was not to setup `single="false"` but `maxLines="100"`, maybe you can have a try:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvVExample"
    android:textColor="#496933"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

If you are using a LinearLayout and above is not working, you can maybe try adding `android:layout_weight="1"` (but `layout_width` will have to be set to `match_parent`).