# Android Downloadable fonts: italic text cut off at start and end

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using the Android O downloadable fonts to apply to my textView, it all works well for normal text style but when the `<item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>` is applied the text gets cut off. See image below.

[image]

I have seen these solutions but not working for me.
[Android TextView hide the text when wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995681/android-textview-hide-the-text-when-wrap)

This library handles this problem easily but it need more work than the Android O support. 
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: try giving some padding to the textview. Maybe it can solve your issue.

Comment: no effect of the padding to the cropping, I tried it

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [Unicode no-break space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) (\u00A0). Before or at the end where the Clipping is possible.

This is because the wrap_contents creates a rectangle and the textview text tries to fit in but in italics some part in the starting or end is clipped because it is outside that rectangle made by wrap_content.

i hope it helps.

p.s it's not the perfect solution but it's the hack that still works.

Comment: Won't work for multi-line text as you won't know where would be the line break!